Logistic Regression Coefficient Interpretation
Hello I'm working on the interpretation of logistic regression. I am not sure whether I understand it fully. Can you help me with it? Really appreciate it.
This is my sample data. I want to study factors impacting the college attendance. The dependent variable is the dummy variable, whether to attend college, the independent variables are family income, a continuous variable,  and whether live in a city, a dummy variable.
# Set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(42)

# Number of observations
n <- 20

# Simulate data
attend_college <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.5)  # 50% chance of attending college
family_income <- rnorm(n, mean = 50000, sd = 15000)  # Family income with mean = $50,000, sd = $15,000
live_in_city <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.6)  # 60% chance of living in a city

# Create a dataframe
simulated_df <- data.frame(AttendCollege = attend_college, FamilyIncome = family_income, LiveInCity = live_in_city)

# Display the first few rows of the dataframe
head(simulated_df)

# Perform logistic regression
model <- glm(AttendCollege ~ FamilyIncome + LiveInCity, family = binomial(link = "logit"), data = simulated_df)

# Display the summary of the logistic regression model
summary(model)

This is the output.
Call:
glm(formula = AttendCollege ~ FamilyIncome + LiveInCity, family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
    data = simulated_df)

Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept)   3.397e-01  1.285e+00   0.264    0.792
FamilyIncome  1.421e-05  2.506e-05   0.567    0.571
LiveInCity   -5.751e-01  1.058e+00  -0.544    0.587

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 25.898  on 19  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 25.367  on 17  degrees of freedom
AIC: 31.367

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4

Can I interpret the relationship between the family income and whether to attend college in this way: each additional dollar of family income increases the odds of attending college by approximately (1.421e-05) *100 = 0.001421%, all else being equal. For example, if family income increases by 1000 dollars, the likelihood of attending college increases by around 0.001421% * 1000 = 1.421 %. Or do I need to calculate the exp(0.001421)? Appreciate your help.
